# I don't understand the merging between C++ and HTML in a piece of code

Tags: html, c++, css

For the past few days I've been tinkering with the Arduino IDE + ESP32 Core and a DOIT ESP32 DEVKITV1.

I want to make a web interface using [Hieromon's AutoConnect](https://github.com/Hieromon/AutoConnect) and I've scrolling through his API's libraries and the thing that I didn't understand at all was the "merging" of HTML and C++.

```
/**< Common html document header. */
const char AutoConnect::_ELM_HTML_HEAD[] PROGMEM = {
  "<!DOCTYPE html>"
  "<html>"
  "<head>"
  "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"
};

/**< LuxBar menu element. */
const char  AutoConnect::_ELM_MENU[]  PROGMEM = {
  "<header id=\"luxbar\" class=\"luxbar-fixed\">"
  "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"luxbar-checkbox\" id=\"luxbar-checkbox\"/>"
  "<div class=\"luxbar-menu luxbar-menu-right luxbar-menu-material-bluegrey\">"
  "<ul class=\"luxbar-navigation\">"
  "<li class=\"luxbar-header\">"
  "<a href=\"" AUTOCONNECT_URI "\" class=\"luxbar-brand\">MENU_TITLE</a>"
  "<label class=\"luxbar-hamburger luxbar-hamburger-doublespin\" id=\"luxbar-hamburger\" for=\"luxbar-checkbox\"><span></span></label>"
  "</li>"
  "<li class=\"luxbar-item\"><a href=\"" AUTOCONNECT_URI_CONFIG "\">Configure new AP</a></li>"
  "<li class=\"luxbar-item\"><a href=\"" AUTOCONNECT_URI_OPEN "\">Open SSIDs</a></li>"
  "<li class=\"luxbar-item\"><a href=\"" AUTOCONNECT_URI_DISCON "\">Disconnect</a></li>"
  "<li class=\"luxbar-item\" id=\"reset\"><a href=\"#rdlg\">Reset...</a></li>"
  "<li class=\"luxbar-item\"><a href=\"HOME_URI\">HOME</a></li>"
  "</ul>"
  "</div>"
  "<div class=\"lap\" id=\"rdlg\"><a href=\"#reset\" class=\"overlap\"></a>"
  "<div class=\"modal_button\"><h2><a href=\"" AUTOCONNECT_URI_RESET "\" class=\"modal_button\">RESET</a></h2></div>"
  "</div>"
  "</header>"
};

/**< The 404 page content. */
const char  AutoConnect::_PAGE_404[] PROGMEM = {
  "{{HEAD}}"
  "<title>Page not found</title>"
  "</head>"
  "<body>"
  "404 Not found"
  "</body>"
  "</html>"
};

/**< The page that started the reset. */
const char  AutoConnect::_PAGE_RESETTING[] PROGMEM = {
  "{{HEAD}}"
  "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"{{UPTIME}};URL=" AUTOCONNECT_URI "\">"
  "<title>AutoConnect resetting</title>"
  "</head>"
  "<body>"
  "<h2>{{RESET}}</h2>"
  "</body>"
  "</html>"
};
```

As you can see, this is the declaration of multiple HTML pages.
It starts with:

```
const char AutoConnect::_ELM_HTML_HEAD[] PROGMEM = {
  "<!DOCTYPE html>"
  "<html>"
  "<head>"
  "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"
};
```

He opened the html and head tag there and never closed them.

He then continued to "making another HTML page"

```
const char  AutoConnect::_PAGE_404[] PROGMEM = {
  "{{HEAD}}"
  "<title>Page not found</title>"
  "</head>"
  "<body>"
  "404 Not found"
  "</body>"
  "</html>"
};
```

And here we find `"{{HEAD}}"` and the closing tags of html and head.

And this goes on.

Now, from what I gather he made a HEAD using `const char AutoConnect::_ELM_HTML_HEAD[] PROGMEM` , that is actually the start of every HTML page.

Now what I don't understand is why is it named HEAD and not _ELM_HTML_HEAD like in the above declaration.

Also why and how exactly do you use it with {{}} (double curly braces). 
I tried looking it up on google but I didn't didn't find an on-the-subject explanation.

Do you think you can help me understand ? Or at least point me towards some useful guide ?

Thank you !

Comment: the double curly brackets are usually used with template engine (think of Angular for instance). So `{{HEAD}}` is a placeholder where some string will be put afterwards, probably representing the header of the web page

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with what the C++ compiler sees:

```
const char AutoConnect::_ELM_HTML_HEAD[] PROGMEM =
{
    "just some (rather long) string literal"
    "anything could stand here, the compiler does not care for..."
};
```

This applies for all members defined that way. Obviously, there are some HTML fragments stored in, but that's irrelevant from C++ point of view.

From C++ point of view, the `{{ [...] }}` fragments are just part of the string, too, and they don't have any meaning in HTML either. They certainly are insertion markers for some standard text pieces to produce the final HTML output – but that needs to be done by the final C++ executable, it is not part of neither C++ nor HTML. So you'll find some code somewhere that does something similar to the following:

```
char const* pattern = [...];
while(*pattern)
{
    char const* start = strstr(pattern, "{{");
    char const* end = strstr(start, "}}");
    std::cout.write(pattern, start - pattern);
    start += 2;
    std::string_view key(start, end - start);
    std::cout << fragments[key]; // assuming some map, mapping id to content
    pattern = end + 2;
}
```

**Be aware that this is incomplete!!!** I do not care for not having found start and end markers (double braces) or for printing the rest of the string, if no replacement marker has been found any more; the real application would need to handle these cases appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The response to your question is probably [here](https://github.com/Hieromon/PageBuilder).

In you case, HEAD is a placeholder the value returned by

```
String AutoConnect::_token_HEAD(PageArgument& args) {
   return String(_ELM_HTML_HEAD);
}
```

Look at:

```
PageElement page404(_PAGE_404, { { "HEAD", std::bind(&AutoConnect::_token_HEAD, this, std::placeholders::_1) } });
String html = page404.build();
```